# How to export data in multiple sheets in php

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have used PHPExcel class in php to export data but PHPExcel version 1.8 is deprecated in 2015.

Can I get any alternative solution for exporting multiple sheets.

Comment: you have the answer right where you read that it is deprecated... what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**PHPSpreadhsheet**](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). This is what the currently deprecated **PHPExcel** library has been continued as.

---

According to the [***docs***](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/worksheets/#adding-a-new-worksheet). You will need to use the [**Composer**](https://getcomposer.org/) package manager to install this library on your machine, by running the following command at the location of installation -

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Include the library in your .php file in the following way -

```
<?php

    // load the classes provided by PHPSpreadSheet
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    // code to create and use worksheet goes here
?>
```

To create/add new worksheets you can use this function -

```
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
```

You can create multiple worksheets by using the above command in a `for()` or `while()` loop.

To get the worksheet and edit it, you can fetch it by index in the following way -

```
$spreadsheet->getSheet(1);
```

The above command will fetch the second sheet from the workbook (since the worksheets are always indexed from "0").

Answer (score 1):

I would recommande using Box/Spout : https://github.com/box/spout if you have to deal with huge data ! (NB : I have no affiliation with this project)

May depend on which PHPExcel functionnalities you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel library has been deprecated. From [Github repository of PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel#phpexcel---deprecated):

> PHPExcel - DEPRECATED
>
> PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project is no
>   longer maintained and should not be used anymore.
>
> All users should migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or
>   another alternative.

### Alternative

**PHPSpreadsheet** ([Github Repository](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)). From Github description:

> PhpSpreadsheet is a library written in pure PHP and providing a set of
>   classes that allow you to read from and to write to different
>   spreadsheet file formats, like Excel and LibreOffice Calc.
>
> PhpSpreadsheet is the next version of PHPExcel. It breaks
>   compatibility to dramatically improve the code base quality
>   (namespaces, PSR compliance, use of latest PHP language features,
>   etc.).

- Official Documentation - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/
- API Documentation - https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/